# Angular 8 - Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask

Tags: angular, angular8, appendchild

**Angular 8 - Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask**

**myfile.html**

```
<div id="loaddynamiccss"></div>
```

**mytypescriptfile.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.LoadPaceTheme('../../../@theme/styles/pace.theme.scss');
  }

 LoadPaceTheme(cssFile: string) {
    /* Loader Pace-Theme for Header */
    //var headE1 = this.document.getElementById('loaddynamiccss');
    var headE1 = <HTMLElement>document.getElementById("loaddynamiccss");
    const newLinkEl = this.document.createElement('link');
    newLinkEl.rel = 'stylesheet';
    newLinkEl.href = cssFile;
    console.log(newLinkEl);
    setTimeout(() => {
      headE1.appendChild(newLinkEl);
    }, 2000);
  }
```

Need help on that ---- Any idea why its giving Cannot read property 'appendChild' ?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```js
const newLinkEl = this.document.createElement('link');
```

to

```js
const newLinkEl = document.createElement('link');
```

Comment: Hi Same issue..

var headE1 = document.getElementById("loaddynamiccss");
    var newLinkEl = document.createElement('link');
    // newLinkEl.appendChild()
    newLinkEl.rel = 'stylesheet';
    newLinkEl.href = cssFile;
    console.log(newLinkEl);
    setTimeout(() => {
      headE1.appendChild(newLinkEl);
    }, 2000);

Comment: Can you please look here in inspector and div have appended link element [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufheby?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpace-theme%2Fpace-theme.component.ts)